Send alert as a push notification
I want to send alert using this endpoint /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/alert/send/generic as a push notification.
Now messages sent using this endpoint are delivered as 'In-app alert' and are visible in Messages in application. Where can I change configuration related to 'user.generic' alert type to send this as push. Is it on institution level or user level configuration?

As the endpoint suggests .../alert/send/generic will send a generic user alert. Using the endpoint will try to send the alert as an in-app message and push notification (if the user has enabled push notifications).
This is not configurable.

Thanks for your response. On the same page it says  Send a simple push alert using a 'user.generic' alert type defined/configurable in the routes above. but my end user is not getting push notification even if phone permissions to get notifications are ON. So can you help me and tell what and where user has to change to get push notifications?

Could you share some details about how you're calling the endpoint as well as the x-request ID for one of your requests that is having the issue?

It seems that push notifications are sent only in specific time windows. We sent alert around 10 am UTC and did not get push notification. After some time around 1pm UTC I got this push I have sent earlier. Also sending next alerts after 1pm UTC were sent as push notifications and we got it immediately
